# How can I write a query that shows the Institutions that have more than one one contact at them?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    CREATE TABLE Institutions
    (
    Institution_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Institution_Name VARCHAR(200))
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Contact_Persons
(
Contact_No INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
First_Name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Last_Name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Institution_ID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (Institution_ID) REFERENCES Institutions(Institution_ID))
```

---

*How can I write a mysql query that shows the Institutions that have more than one one Contact Person at them? The Query should show Institution_ID and Institution_Name from Table Institutions. The following Query works but It only shows Institution_ID. I want to see Institution_Name too. I think there must be a join between these two tables. Please help.*

```
SELECT Institution_ID
FROM Contact_Persons
GROUP BY Institution_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT I.Institution_ID,I.Institution_name
FROM Contact_Persons as C inner join Institutions as I on 
C.Institution_ID=I.Institution_ID
GROUP BY I.Institution_ID,I.Institution_name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Comment: "The Query should show Institution_ID and Institution_Name "

Answer (score 0):

You were right, you just need to join your two tables, and make sure you also group by everything you want to select (unless it is an aggregate), so in this case add `Institution_Name` to the group by clause:

```
SELECT i.Institution_ID, i.Institution_Name
FROM Contact_Persons AS cp
    INNER JOIN Institutions AS i
        ON i.Institution_ID = cp.Institution_ID
GROUP BY i.Institution_ID, i.Institution_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```